# jquery "hasClass()" not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to hide a div if another div has a class.

I've created a very basic example [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/sC3Yq/1/)

I need the div on the bottom to hide when the word "click" is.. well.. clicked. It adds a class to the middle div just fine, but it seems `hasClass()` doesn't want to work?

**NOTE:** The structure needs to be like this. If "click" is clicked, modify the middle div (add class?), and manipulate the bottom div based on the middle div. With this setup - I can't just do "if CLICK is clicked, slideUp() the bottom div".

Also, once "ok" or "cancel" is clicked, it will revert, because the middle div will no longer have the class. Provided that's the method I can get working here, haha.

Comment: you dod realize, in your example, hasclass is only called once. Its not an event, its not going to fire every time that element has that class. hasClass is a function intended to be used **during** an event to check if a specific element has a specific class

Answer (score 5, accepted):

your `if` statement is outside of any function, so there is no reason for it to be called after the script is loaded.

[See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9mv6M/), I think that's what you want.

Answer (score 5):

On a side note, another variation to check if there's a class is:

```
if ( $('body.className').length ) {
```

Still recommend hasClass though. Just nice to see variation sometimes.

Comment: I think you meant to add a space between body and .className

Comment: I'm checking if the body element has the class

Answer (score 3):

This is only getting called once, when the script loads.  You need to have make sure it gets called in your `.click(...)` handler.

```
if($('#timestampdiv').hasClass('hidepub')) {
    $('#major-publishing-actions').slideUp('slow');
}
```

Comment: I was just typing this but you beat me. Because all of your events are linked to anchor <a> tags you can put this if statement into an event similar to: `$("a").on("click", function(){ if($("#timestampdiv").hasClass("hidepub")){ $("#major-publishing-actions").slideUp("slow");});`

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by others, you don't  have a call to `if` on all click event handlers.  Create a custom function with statement inside `if` and call it on all click handler.

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sC3Yq/3/)

Answer (score 1):

After you append the class to the DOM element, this should properly hide the element.

```
$('.element').click(function()
{
    $('.thisElement').addClass('hidepub');
    if($('.thisElement').hasClass('hidepub')) {
         $('.thisElement').hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine them all into one function - And you want that check to be inside the click functions

You can reduce the addclass removeclass by using [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) and passing in a condition

```
$('a.edit-timestamp,a.save-timestamp,a.cancel-timestamp').click(function() {
    var $tsdiv = $("#timestampdiv");
    // add class showpub if edit is clicked
    $tsdiv.toggleClass('showpub',$(this).hasClass('edit-timestamp'));
    // add class hidepub only if it wasn't edit that was clicked
    $tsdiv.toggleClass('hidepub',!$(this).hasClass('edit-timestamp'));  

    // then do your toggle                            
    if ($tsdiv.hasClass('hidepub')) {
        $('#major-publishing-actions').slideUp('slow');
    }else{
        $('#major-publishing-actions').slideDown('slow');
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JPcge/

You can reverse it by swapping the logic passed into the toggleClass() methods